# ng-show/hide is not working on dynamically added html

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to add dynamic HTML (like below) and have ng-show/hide work correctly?

A work around is to find the plots I want to interchange and .show()/.hide() appropriately.

Background:
I'm dynamically appending plots on a page (using Highcharts) to HTML id 'space-for-HC'.  I am showing grades with and without weighting. I want to interchange these plots using a checkbox (ng-model='Weighted").

JS:

```
$scope.plot_it_all = function(response) {
    let schools = Object.keys(response.data);
    schools.forEach(function(school){
        angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-HC')).append(

'<div>' +
'    <div class="ng-scope" ng-hide="Weighted" id="HC-container-grades-' + school + '" style="min-width: 600px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>' +
'    <div class="ng-scope" ng-show="Weighted" id="HC-container-grades-weighted' + school + '" style="min-width: 600px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>' +
'</div>'

        );
        $scope.plot_school(school, response);
    });
};
```

Disclaimer: This is my first angular app

Comment: you need to use `$compile`.

Comment: ah! Thanks! Let me get that in

Comment: Can you use custom directives? Actually, you use AngularJs like JQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this kind of dom manipulation should be done in directives.

where u can use angular compile service `$compile`